# How to monitor space usage on ASM diskgroups

Tags: oracle, oracle-asm, oracle-database-appliance

Last night the recovery area on one of our Oracle Database Appliances went full. This was reported in one of the database alert logs, and we were able to clear out some space before the next log switch, at which point the production would have come to a halt.

It certainly would have been nice to have a little more warning, like when the disk group was 70% full.

What options do we have for monitoring disk usage inside ASM?

Comment: If you want monitoring and alerting of oracle components, I would really recommend setting up an Oracle Enterprise Manager installation. It will provide you with ASM monitoring, can send alerts via email, snmp, etc. https://oracle-base.com/articles/13c/cloud-control-13cr1-installation-on-oracle-linux-6-and-7

Comment: @Patrick, interestingly we spent more time managing OEM than we did Oracle DB, so we discontinued our use of OEM some time back.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use `asmcmd`. For example:

```
[oracle@oel61 ~]$ . oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [+ASM] ? +ASM
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /u01/app/oracle
[oracle@oel61 ~]$ asmcmd lsdg
State    Type    Rebal  Sector  Block       AU  Total_MB  Free_MB  Req_mir_free_MB  Usable_file_MB  Offline_disks  Voting_files  Name
MOUNTED  EXTERN  N         512   4096  1048576     30708    28479                0           28479              0             N  DATA/
[oracle@oel61 ~]$
```

Or get the info directly from the ASM Oracle instance:

```
[oracle@oel61 ~]$ . oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [+ASM] ? +ASM
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /u01/app/oracle
[oracle@oel61 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Thu Mar 7 10:44:44 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Automatic Storage Management option

SQL> SELECT name, free_mb, total_mb, free_mb/total_mb*100 as percentage 
     FROM v$asm_diskgroup;

NAME                  FREE_MB   TOTAL_MB PERCENTAGE
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
DATA                    28479      30708 92.7413052

SQL>
```

Comment: OEM also has the info when you have that, and can probably be coerced into raising alerts. The `v$asm_diskgroup` view is also available on the "client" database(s) (might depend on exact versions), which is pretty practical if you already have custom monitoring scripts in there.

Comment: The v$asm_diskgroup view is very convenient. Thanks! Although, the TOTAL_MB and FREE_MB columns appear to show raw capacity as opposed to usable space, is that right?

Comment: See [Managing Capacity in Disk Groups](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e18951/asmdiskgrps.htm#CHDGGGAD) for the details on that view, @Roy.

Comment: 2nd option useful. Hope this may also useful here:
https://ora-data.blogspot.com/2016/12/how-to-find-details-of-tablespace.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
col gname form a10
col dbname form a10
col file_type form a14

SELECT
    gname,
    dbname,
    file_type,
    round(SUM(space)/1024/1024) mb,
    round(SUM(space)/1024/1024/1024) gb,
    COUNT(*) "#FILES"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            gname,
            regexp_substr(full_alias_path, '[[:alnum:]_]*',1,4) dbname,
            file_type,
            space,
            aname,
            system_created,
            alias_directory
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    concat('+'||gname, sys_connect_by_path(aname, '/')) full_alias_path,
                    system_created,
                    alias_directory,
                    file_type,
                    space,
                    level,
                    gname,
                    aname
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            b.name            gname,
                            a.parent_index    pindex,
                            a.name            aname,
                            a.reference_index rindex ,
                            a.system_created,
                            a.alias_directory,
                            c.type file_type,
                            c.space
                        FROM
                            v$asm_alias a,
                            v$asm_diskgroup b,
                            v$asm_file c
                        WHERE
                            a.group_number = b.group_number
                        AND a.group_number = c.group_number(+)
                        AND a.file_number = c.file_number(+)
                        AND a.file_incarnation = c.incarnation(+) ) START WITH (mod(pindex, power(2, 24))) = 0
                AND rindex IN
                    (
                        SELECT
                            a.reference_index
                        FROM
                            v$asm_alias a,
                            v$asm_diskgroup b
                        WHERE
                            a.group_number = b.group_number
                        AND (
                                mod(a.parent_index, power(2, 24))) = 0
                            and a.name like '&&db_name'
                    ) CONNECT BY prior rindex = pindex )
        WHERE
            NOT file_type IS NULL
            and system_created = 'Y' )
WHERE
    dbname like '&db_name'
GROUP BY
    gname,
    dbname,
    file_type
ORDER BY
    gname,
    dbname,
    file_type
/
```